# creating a constructor of a subclass

Tags: inheritance

[image][image]

when I create the constructor for the sundae class, eclipse says I must explicitly invoke another constructor but I don't understand how to fix it.
And in my main method,when I create a new object of type Cake eclipse says no enclosing instance of type DessertCafe is accessible but it worked when i create the second one. can anyone help me fix them

Answer (score 0):

If `Sundae` extends `IceCream` (a dubious model, but I digress), then creating a `Sundae` implicitly has to create an `IceCream` first; and you've explicitly given one constructor with an argument (`cost`).  Therefore you have to tell the `Sundae` constructor what to pass to the `IceCream` constructor.

That's what the `super` keyword does.

```
public Sundae( int topping ) {
    super( 5 ); // <- what's the cost?  5 bucks?
    // ...
}
```

Often, if you extend a class with an unknown constructor argument, you have to make your new constructor have that argument too:

```
public Sundae( int topping, int cost ) {
    super( cost );
    // ...
}
```

When you're just starting out with Java, it's better to include all the optional stuff.  Although it's optional to put a call to `super` in your class constructor, if you *don't* put one, the compiler injects one that looks like

```
super();
```

which calls a 0-arg constructor of the base class.  Although it's optional to include a constructor at all in Java, if you did *not* specify any constructor in the base class, the compiler inserts one that looks like this:

```
public BaseClass() {
    super();
}
```

And furthermore, if you *did* specify a constructor in the base class that has arguments, then the compiler does *not* create an implicit 0-arg constructor.  That makes any attempts to call `super()` with no arguments, such as the compiler-generated such calls mentioned above, erroneous.

Regarding your `Cake` problem, you've declared a class inside a class without making that nested class `static`.  That means you can't instantiate it without an enclosing class instance.  You should declare all nested classes `static` when first starting out in Java.

Comment: how about the error when I create a new object of type Cake how can I fix it and I don't understand why is it an error anyway

Comment: can't help with `Cake` without seeing the source of `Cake` and `Dessert`.

Comment: I added the code of Cake and Dessert in my question, can you take a look

Comment: I added to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you need to call the constructor of the parent class you are subclassing before doing anything in your child class.

Lets suppose your parent class is as below:

```
package my.icecream.shop;

abstract public class IceCream {

    protected String mFlavour;

    public IceCream(String flavor) {
        mFlavour = flavour;
    }

    abstract public void serve();
}
```

And you subclass it as **Sundae** as follows:

```
package my.icecream.shop;

public class Sundae extends IceCream {

    protected int mServes;

    public Sundae(String flavour, int serves) {
        // this super call is important and must come first to anything
        super(flavour);
        mServes = serves;
    }
}
```